# Using istream_iterator to read strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, istream-iterator

I don't understand exactly how reading a string via iterators is different from reading it directly. To exemplify, consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    string str{istream_iterator<char>(cin),{}};
    cout << str << endl;

    string str1;
    cin >> str1;
    cout << str1 << endl;
}
```

It is obvious what it does, it reads `str` using an `istream_iterator`, and reads `str1` via traditional method. I have 2 questions:

1. The only way of ending the reading via string iterators is to send a `CTRL+D` (Unix), which also terminates the program, so the second part is not executed. Is there any way around this?
2. When reading with iterators, it doesn't matter if I input whitespaces (space, \t, \n), the iterator keeps reading. Why is this behaviour different from the one when reading directly via `cin >>`?

Comment: try this in C++03 `string str{istream_iterator<char>(cin),{}};`

Comment: ah my bad, I am already too used to curly brace initialization

Comment: @TemplateRex no worries :) I just used C++11 specific features, that's why the tag. Of course the question is not about C++11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I don't understand exactly how reading a string via iterators is different from reading it directly.

The difference in your example is that the first reads the entire stream, while the second reads a single word (until the first space).

More generally, iterators can be used to fill other containers (e.g. using `istream_iterator<int>` to fill `vector<int>`), or passed directly to algorithms that work with forward iterators.

> The only way of ending the reading via string iterators is to send a `CTRL+D` (Unix), which also terminates the program

It doesn't terminate the program, it just closes the input stream. But you won't be able to read anything else from the input after doing that; as it stands, your program doesn't make sense since it tries to read beyond the end of `cin`.

> When reading with iterators, it doesn't matter if I input whitespaces (space, \t, \n), the iterator keeps reading. Why is this behaviour different from the one when reading directly via `cin >>`?

Because that's how `>>` is defined to work with strings.

Comment: Thanks, got the second part. However I cannot stop the reading via iterators. CTRL+D quits, CTRL+Z just stops the process (UNIX)

Comment: @vsoftco: Sorry, I was wrong, you do want `CRTL-D`. But you won't be able to read from the input after that, since there is no more input.

Comment: Mike: OK, so basically using iterators to construct/insert elements in a `string` via `cin` is just a bad idea... But is at least any way to not quit the program after CTRL+D? I tried `cin.ignore` and `cin.reset` with no luck.

Comment: @vsoftco: It's a good idea if you want to consume the entire stream, and a bad idea if you want to do something else.

Comment: Yes, I see, thanks. Again the only thing that I still don't know is how to continue the program after the CTRL+D

Comment: @vsoftco: CTRL-D doesn't quit the program, it just closes the input stream. Your program quits because it runs to the end of `main` after the input stream is closed; `cin >> str` returns immediately because `cin` is no longer valid. It could do anything that doesn't involve reading from `cin`.

Answer (score 3):

1. If you've reached the end of the stream there can't be anything more to read.
2. The end iterator provided in the range constructor represents the end of the input. When an invalid character or the end of the stream is met (`EOF` is found), the start iterator will equal the end iterator, and that's how it stops. Stream iterators do discard whitespace so if you print your string it should contain no whitespace.

   The second extraction is formatted uses whitespace to delimit input, and that is why only one word is read.

Comment: I used also `cin.clear(); cin.ignore();` between the reads, but still cannot stop from quitting after getting `CTRL+D`. Understood the second part, but cannot make it quit reading via iterators without quitting/stopping the program.

Comment: @vsoftco I thought you were using stream buffer iterators, not stream iterators. You can enter in whitespace but it is still discarded.

Comment: `cin.clear()` won't reopen the input stream once it's been closed. The first read consumes the entire stream, so there's nothing to read afterwards.